# How do I create and save an image file from media binaries using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, http, httprequest

I'm working on a real estate website for a client. I have direct access to Trestle data. I have successfully pulled all relevant listing fields I want, but am having a really tough time figuring out how images work. See this link for the Trestle documentation I'm using: https://docs-trestle.corelogic.com/Subtopic/MultiplePhotos

Here is the code I'm using to test the output for a specific property. I have already authenticated myself, with $token allowing me to access the data. Note this is being done on a wordpress site.

```
$url = 'https://api-prod.corelogic.com/trestle/odata/Property(361082372)/Media/All';
$headers = array(
    'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token
);
$args = array(
    'headers'   => $headers
);
$response = wp_remote_get($url, $args);
var_dump($response['body']);
```

Here is a screenshot of the output I'm getting. It has data about the image, but I'm somewhat lost as to how to turn this into a legitimate image or download the image file itself. Ideally I just want to download the images. Can anyone steer me in the right direction? Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Looks like you should be able to `fwrite` that data to a file as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing to a file.

```
$response = wp_remote_get($url, $args);
// replace sample.jpg with the path and name of the real file you want to write.
$fp = fopen('sample.jpg', 'w');
if ( $fp ) {
    fwrite($fp, $response['body']);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

If you want to see the actual image, you can use [ImageCreateFromString()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php).

```
ImageCreateFromString($response['body']);
```

This will output the image to the browser.

Comment: Thank you; I think this was on the right track but due to the nature of the doc I had to parse some excess text out. Will post my code below; got it working.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you've linked to states the response is a multipart mime document so you will need to parse the mime packet response and extract the image(s) from it, then save them to your server.

There is a PECL extension for parsing mime message called [mailparse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php), in addition there are several wrapper classes for this if you google around.

Comment: Thank you; this was my first time dealing with a multipart mime document and I found it odd that I had to manually parse it instead of it being returned as structured data. I finally have it all working, and have the images successfully downloading to a chosen directory. Will post my code below.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working - not sure if it's the cleanest way. If there's a better way to parse through this data I'm all ears! I appreciate the responses. Anyway, I found that "--TRM" was a string only found before a new image and never within one, so I initially exploded the string on that. I then did another explode on the last bit of text before the binary image data came through, which was "Content-type: image/jpeg". From here I trimmed the sides and was able to loop through and save each image to a file. Code below:

```
$response = wp_remote_get($url, $args);
$images = array_slice(explode('--TRM', $response['body']), 1, -1);
$iteration = 0;
//Loop through each iteration of an "image"
foreach($images as $image) {
    $iteration = $iteration + 1;
    //explode on the last common text, take the last part, trim all whitespace and blank lines
    $item = trim(explode('Content-Type: image/jpeg', $image)[1]);
    file_put_contents(getcwd()."/listing-images/".$mls."/".$iteration.".jpeg", $item);
}
```